# Java typewriter effect

Tags: java

Hello I want to have a typewrite effect on the screen where every few seconds a letter appear after the previous one. I was thinking about having a string with all the text I want to write and every second I would take the first char of that string, remove it and then add it to a different string. For example:

```
  String text = "hello world";
  String onscreenText = "";
```

Then onscreenText would have "h" in it and text would have everything but the "h" in it and so on. How can I remove the first char from a string and add it to the next string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the string one character at a time, with a small delay between each character. To achieve this, you need a loop to print out each character from the string, with a small pause for each iteration. The `sleep()` command can be used to pause the script.

```
String text = "hello world";
int i;
for(i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
    System.out.printf("%c", text.charAt(i));
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);//0.5s pause between characters
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

**Update** using the `drawString()` method to draw a substring:

```
String text = "hello world";
int i;
for(i = 1; i <= text.length(); i++){
    g.drawString(text.subString(0, i), x, y);//Where g is your Graphics object and x and y are the coordinates you want to draw at
    try{
        Thread.sleep(500);//0.5s pause between characters
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it ? because `print()` method is wrong

Comment: I will be drawing it with a drawstring on to a frame, does that matter?

Comment: It was meant to be `printf()`; it has been corrected.

Comment: @jackkennedy you can substitute the drawing method instead of printing with `printf()`, but you would have to account for the offset for each character relative to the starting point.

Comment: @Andrew I cant get it to work for drawstring could you rewrite it please

Comment: Heres what I have, it works but it goes backwards:  for(int i = 0; i < onA.length(); i++){
   if(ttime >= ttimer){
    A = onA.substring(i);
      ttime = 0;
      }else{
       ttime++;
      }
  }

Comment: I updated the answer to include `drawString()`. Note: you must declare `(Graphics) g`, `(int) x`, and `(int) y`

Comment: @Andrew yes I could do that part but it does the typewriter effect backwards it displays the full string then slowly takes the end character away from it. How can I fix it .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce your String you can call: text = text.substring(1,text.length) but of course only when there is more than one char inside. The rest with thread delay was already explained by the other posters. Perhaps you can also have a look at Timer class to schedule delayed tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Super Simple to and easy. Don't pay attention to the extended TextView class created. Lets make it simple and easy for everyone. Check it out. First create a class called Typewriter. Then copy and paste this code in that class. close the class.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Typewriter {

    private String sText = new String();
    private int index;
    private long mDelay = 100;

    TextView textView;

    public Typewriter(TextView tView) {
        textView = tView;
    }

    public void animateText(String string) {
        sText = string;
        index = 0;

        textView.setText("");

        new Handler().removeCallbacks(characterAdder);
        new Handler().postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
     }

    private Runnable characterAdder = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(sText.subSequence(0, index++));

            if (index <= sText.length()) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(characterAdder, mDelay);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now after you created that class the new Class that you want to implement this animation feature to is super simple.
Lets say for example you want to add it new a class called MainActivity.

```
import com.utilities.Typewriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Typewriter writer;

    private TextView tv_textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv_textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_textView);
        writer = new Typewriter(tv_textView);
        writer.animateText("Super Simple Animation");
    }
}
```

Thats it and your done. Super Simple leave me votes thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out I am using this

```
class TypingBot extends Thread{
    String textToAnimate;
    int delayInMilliSeconds;
    public TypingBot(String s, int delayInMilliSeconds){
        this.textToAnimate = s;
        this.delayInMilliSeconds = delayInMilliSeconds;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < textToAnimate.length() ; i++){
            System.out.print(textToAnimate.charAt(i));
            try{
                Thread.sleep(delayInMilliSeconds);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TypingAnimation {
    public static void startAnimation(String textToAnimate, int waitForMillis){
        TypingBot typingBot = new TypingBot(textToAnimate, waitForMillis);
        typingBot.isDaemon();
        typingBot.start();

        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        try{
            currentThread.join(waitForMillis);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        startAnimation("Krishna Wadhwani Is The Best Programmer", 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).